# I created a custom theme, deleted it and then can't delete it from AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

So I tried to create a custom theme to my preference_category file, but then decided to delete it. I deleted a theme from styles.xml and the string from AndroidManifest.xml. When I build the project, it is always coming back "from the dead". And every time I delete it, it is recovering. And the string android:theme="@style/Theme.Custom" like was never deleted! The error i got is

> Error:(51, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Custom').
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/lisa/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   Information:BUILD FAILED

And not only this happens. My ManifestFile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.tenderplan"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/notif"
    android:label="Tenderplan"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.tenderplan.activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="Tenderplan"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.tenderplan.activities.LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.tenderplan.activities.ElementActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.tenderplan.activities.SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Custom" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.tenderplan.activities.EditActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.tenderplan.activities.AddKeyActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.tenderplan.activities.AnalyticsActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.tenderplan.activities.AnalyticsCPActivity" />
</application>
```

In Manifest these strings are in red color:

1. `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
2. `android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >`
3. supports-screens
4. `android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/notif"`
5. `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`
   and many others with themes.

This is my styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Also,my `import com.example.tenderplan.R;` can't be found in activities.

Could you help me find the right answer?

Comment: Have u tried by cleaning project and run?

Comment: check where exactly showing error "manifest" in build folder or in src folder?

Comment: Yes I cleaned and restarted few times but the same mistakes.

In build folder.

Comment: can u delete build folder manually and try once

Comment: Yes, I have just done it, but still no progress and the mistakes are the same

Answer (score 0):

Your `SettingsActivity` still has the theme `Theme.Custom` set, which does not exist in the styles.xml anymore. Remove the line `android:theme="@style/Theme.Custom"` from the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: I have said that I deleted a theme from styles.xml and the string from AndroidManifest.xml. When I build the project, it is always coming back "from the dead". And every time I delete it, it is recovering. Somehow it thinks that I do not removing this line and adds it itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the answer after something similar happened to me. You need to remove the custom theme from 3 places:

1. Android Manifest File
2. Values\Styles.xml file
3. Your_Project\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml

After removing all occurrences of the custom theme from all of these places, rebuild gradle.

This worked for me, check it out